# How to add more than 1 signee to OnledgerAsset().generateSpend in the command

Tags: corda

In the current implementation of the OnledgerAsset().generateSpend, it seems like the command signing keys is only the owner of the fungible state. What if we want to have more than 1 signee for the moveCommand(). For example to move cash, besides the owner of the State object, I would want a third party to sign-off on this transaction as well. Are there ways to override this?

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V2/finance/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/asset/OnLedgerAsset.kt

Answer (score 0):

With OwnableStates, only the owner stores the state in their vault. As such, they're the only required signer in moving the cash.

Overriding this would require a change to the cash contract itself which in turn would require the entire network adopt the new contract.

You could potentially look at encumbrances, but this would require the cash be encumbered before the fact. The third party would need to encumber the cash states before the current owner receives them.

Another option would be to look at a composite key between the owner and the third party. Again, this would need to be in place before the owner receives the cash.

Comment: Yes with OwnableState, only the owner stores the state in its vault. But as i understand, this logic is limited to storing the state in local vault and is not valid for signing the transactions. All participants in the state can take part of signing the transaction.